# Converting Columns to Rows based on specific column value

Tags: sql, hana

I have a problem to fill a new column from a previous column where the values are calculated.

Current output:

|  | date | column1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01.01.2022 | 0 |
| A | 02.01.2022 | 1 |
| A | 03.01.2022 | 2 |
| A | 04.01.2022 | 3 |
| A | 05.01.2022 | 4 |
| B | 01.01.2023 | 0 |
| B | 02.01.2023 | 1 |
| B | 03.01.2023 | 2 |
| B | 04.01.2023 | 3 |
| C | 01.01.2024 | 0 |
| C | 02.01.2024 | 1 |
| C | 03.01.2024 | 2 |
| C | 04.01.2024 | 3 |
| C | 05.01.2024 | 4 |

[image]

Required output:

|  | date | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01.01.2022 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 02.01.2022 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 03.01.2022 | 2 | 2 |
| A | 04.01.2022 | 3 | 3 |
| A | 05.01.2022 | 4 | 3 |
| B | 01.01.2023 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 02.01.2023 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 03.01.2023 | 2 | 2 |
| B | 04.01.2023 | 3 | 4 |
| C | 01.01.2024 | 0 | etc |
| C | 02.01.2024 | 1 | etc |
| C | 03.01.2024 | 2 | etc |
| C | 04.01.2024 | 3 | etc |
| C | 05.01.2024 | 4 | etc |

[image]

As you can see, when there is an accordance between previous year/month in column1 (weample 0, 1 etc.) it should display in the row in column2.

When we have in current year less days than in previous year (like A and B), the highest day from previous year in column1 (A) should have the highest number from column1 (B) in column2 (A).

When we have in current year more days than in previous year (like B and C), the highest day from previous year in column1 (B) would have the highest number from column1 (C) in column2 (A).

I tried to solve this issue with a substring and case syntax without a good result.

Comment: 'without a good result' ... What exactly have you tried, why didn't that work / what wasn't 'good' about it?

Comment: I don't get the logic, that you are trying to implement. You are filling the values of col2 with future values of col1. This is different from your description, where you pull previous values. E.g. why does '4.1.2023' fetch the value from '5.1.2024' if there is a value for '4.1.2024' existing?

Comment: don't see any logic as well. You are filling last date measurement of B into A (col2) and C into B (col2) with different pattern. What is the busines logic behind that?